# Is Mavericks available to a 13-inch Late 2007 MacBook, despite everything?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, upgrade, compatibility

Apple makes it quite clear to which models Mavericks is available.

So, I have a 13-inch Late 2007 MacBook (not-Pro, running 10.7.5), which shouldn't be supported.

> [image]

But when I open App Store, there it is: OS X Mavericks with a "FREE UPGRADE" button. That is somewhat surprising. I assume that App Store "knows" which model it is on. Now, I don't think I even want Mavericks on that MacBook, but I do wonder.

What would happen if I press that button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the following alert box:

"**We could not complete your purchase.**

OS X Mavericks cannot be installed on this computer."

You then get two options. The first button is Learn More, which takes you to the system requirements page, and the other button simply says Ok.

Nothing gets downloaded.

Comment: LOL, no need to consider it then. :)